# linux kernel idle tick eater (or what will be current task_struct when CPU is 0%)

Tags: linux-kernel, idle-processing

What process will be pointed by "current" pointer in linux kernel, when CPU load is 0% and there isn't any ready-to-run process?

Consider situation without any power-saving. 
What is the name of this process? I think task with PID 0 will be running and code will be

```
rep nop
```

or

```
HLT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current will be pid 0, process swapper or the last process, which called blocking syscall?

http://oreilly.com/catalog/linuxkernel/chapter/ch10.html

> Notice that if the runqueue list is
>   empty (no runnable process exists
>   except for swapper), the cycle is not
>   entered and next points to init_task.
>   Moreover, if all processes in the
>   runqueue list have a priority lesser
>   than or equal to the priority of prev,
>   no process switch will take place and
>   the old process will continue to be
>   executed.